# Django apps shared python api client

Tags: python, django, api

Let's say I have an external python client that I use as a data source. Let's call it api. It's a pretty standard API, so creating a session object is easy and allows you to connect to the data source. It is thread safe.

I have a few Django apps that will depend on this api, and I'd like to have as few handles to this api per site as possible (one per process I'm guessing).

I was thinking of two approaches:

1. Write a non Django slim wrapper around my API that guarantees only one session object is created per site. Add that to my Django app dependencies.
2. Write a Django app with a custom signal that sends the instance once connected.

It's one of these the best approach, or is there a more ad hoc way?

Comment: You can use middleware as well before proceeding to request it will done your task.

Comment: Why can't you cache the data from api to something like redis? there could be a background task that updates the cache in case there is change in API data

Comment: @user2707389 caching the data could be done, but that's not really the issue here. I need access to a session instance to be able to do queries in my models/views. For the moment each Django view will just create an api object instance and use it if needed, but that means you have the extra overhead of connecting once per app